# MySQL knows the common column, how?

Tags: mysql, sql

I usually perform a JOIN between two tables using a common column, in this case 'product_code'.

Now comes this query that does it without a join:

```
SELECT `rp_products`.`product_code`, `rp_log`.`customer_id`, `rp_products`.`product_name`
FROM rp_products, rp_log
WHERE (`rp_log`.`customer_id` = '111')
ORDER BY `rp_products`.`product_code` ASC, `rp_log`.`customer_id` ASC
```

That returns:

```
product_code    customer_id     product_name
105             111             Paintballs 2000PBS
105             111             Paintballs 2000PBS
106             111             Gloves
106             111             Gloves
```

What I want to know, is how is it showing the correct 'product_name' without joining the 'product_code' between the tables? product_code is not a primary key or anything like that. product_name is the name of both columns in the tables.

- **rp_log** stores the customer_id, product_code, and date of purchase (not shown here).
- **rp_products** stores product_code, price (not shown here) and product_name.

Thank for for your time,
Evan.

Comment: You select the product_name from the rp_products table, so it will show up in every row of the resultset

Comment: Yes, but product_code 106 for example matches "Gloves", and displays it for every result. The rp_products table only has gloves listed once. It looks like there is a join but I did not specify what column to use, but it knows already.

EDIT: If it helps anyone, my tables are in MyISAM.

Comment: You may find elucidation by running the same query with `EXPLAIN` in front of your `SELECT`.  This will show details about the JOIN operation, although @mu has pretty well answered this one already.

Comment: I've ran the query with EXPLAIN, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EX07l.png

Although im not sure what this means, it says "Using where; Using join buffer"  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing a cross product of the entire `rp_products` table and the sub-table of `rp_log` which has a `customer_id` of 111. I'd guess that you have two 111 entries in `rp_log` and two entries in `rp_products`; then each entry in each table (or sub-table) in the join will be pair with each entry in the other to produce the four (= 2 × 2) rows in your result set.

Including more columns from `rp_log` and `rp_products` might clarify things for you.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I only have one entry for gloves in rp_products, and about 50 enties for client 111 in rp_log. I only gave the 4 results in my question because the results page is huge. There is also no product_name in rp_log.

Comment: @Evan: The analysis still applies, just the numbers will be different. There is no join (the join is a lie...), just a cross product. The duplicates that you're seeing are caused by the 50 entries for client 111; you should see 50 paintballs, 50 gloves, etc.

Comment: Could you please look at the screenshot I just posted above, and let me know if the Join Buffer means anything or is this still correct?

Comment: I just checked this, and you are correct! There are 50 entries for client 111 and it shows each product_code 50 times. I still haven't got my head around how exactly it can grab the right product name for each one and display it 50 times each, but knowing that this isn't actually 'joining' is enough for me and to use JOIN. Thank you!

Comment: @Evan: You're grabbing both the code and name from `rp_products`, they match up because both columns always come from the same `rp_products` row.